# usage of the append function of list in python

Tags: python, list

```
class Solution:    
    # @param num, a list of integer
    # @return a list of lists of integers
        def permute(self, num):
            self.res = [];
            self.dfs(num, 0)
            return self.res

        def dfs(self, num, level):
            if level == len(num):
                self.res.append(num)
                print(num)
                return
            for i in range(level, len(num)):
                num[i], num[level] = num[level], num[i]
                self.dfs(num, level+1)
                num[i], num[level] = num[level], num[i]
```

The above code is used to generate all permutations given a collection of numbers. For example,
num = [1, 3]
The result will be:
[1 3], [3, 1]

But there is a bug for the above code that I don't understand, which is `self.res.append(num)`.
If I change it to `self.res.append(num[:])`, then the code is correct. Can anyone explain why?

Using `self.res.append(num)`, the result is:

[1, 3], [1, 3]

Using `self.res.append(num[:])`, the result is:

[1, 3], [3, 1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements of a python `list` are references to other objects. When you append using `self.res.append(num)`, the list is grown by 1 element, and the last element is set to refer to the object pointed to by `num`.

Now in the first case, there are 2 references to the same `list` object. As `self.res[0]` and `self.res[1]` refer to the same object, all changes performed through either are also visible through the other.

In the second case, using `num[:]`, `[:]` operator makes a new list that is copy of the original.

---

For general algorithm for creating all permutations of a given collection of elements, use the [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> print(list(permutations([1, 3])))
[(1, 3), (3, 1)]
```

Comment: You could also use `list(num)` to obtain a copy of num.

Comment: True. The `[:]` is the general way to make a copy of a sequence if mutable, whereas `list()` is a way to make a list with elements of an iterable